# best way to create a Drupal RSS feed without views

Tags: xml, drupal, rss

I’m looking for a little help/guidance on what the best practice may be for creating an RSS feed from a Drupal 6.19 site.

I’m creating the RSS for the specific requirements of a third party vendor from a site that is nothing but CCK fields. I believe part of the requirement is to load the xml file to an FTP that is not part of the site (not 100% about that).

Since the feed would be more product/analytics based, I’m not sure views2 would be the way to deliver the feed, especially if the file needs to live somewhere else.

I’d like to build it from scratch, but will Drupal recognize it? and possibly at a distance?

any advise would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Drupal has its own feed system at admin/config/services/rss-publishing . I am using d7 so the path might be a bit different.

Having said that I don't think that would suit your needs.

The only way I can think creating a rss feed without views is using the node_load() function. Where you get the node filtered based on the unix time stamp on the created field.

Then making a xml file from that data. For further reading check out

http://magpierss.sourceforge.net/

Cheers,
vishal

Comment: Thanks for the help, i ended up having to build a custom module to get the structure i was looking for. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking for an answer to this question, it's actually very simple. Here's an example of how you might create a feed of nodes 1, 2, 3, and 4, at the /myfeed URL:

```
function mymodule_menu() {
  $items = array();
  $items['myfeed'] = array(
    'title' => 'My Feed',
    'page callback' => 'mymodule_custom_feed',
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );
  return $items;
}

function mymodule_custom_feed() {
  $nids = array(1, 2, 3, 4);
  // (some hardcoded nids for simplicity, but you probably want to do a db_select
  $link = url(current_path(), array('absolute' => true));
  $channel = array(
    'title' => t('My Custom Feed'),
    'link' => $link,
  );
  node_feed($nids, $channel);
}
```